# How to sanitize HTML in the filename - Javascript Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

i am very new to javascript/coffescript

- I have no clue how to go about sanitizing an HTML in the filename
- i would like to sanitize this html `<br><small>Uploading #{data.files[0].name}</small>` in the below code

if one could offer me some guidance would be grateful

filename: document_upload.coffee

```
#= require async_actions

$ () ->
  $('#file-upload').fileupload
    dataType: 'json'
    submit: (e, data) ->
      if fileValid data.files[0]
        el = $('.document.uploading').clone().append "<br><small>Uploading #{data.files[0].name}</small>"
        debugger
        $('.documents').append el.css 'display', 'block'
      else
        return false
    done: (e, data) ->
      window.location.reload()
    fail: (e, data) ->
      el = $ '.documents .document:last-child'
      el.addClass 'error'
      el.children().fadeOut 300, () ->
        el.find('span').removeClass('fa-refresh fa-spin').addClass 'fa-warning'
        el.find('small').text 'Upload error'
        el.children().fadeIn()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of sanitization libraries you could try out:

- [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html)
- [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/jitbit/HtmlSanitizer)
- [Caja (by Google)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-caja/wikis/JsHtmlSanitizer.wiki)
- [Other packages via NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:sanitize)